# Is there a Deployment build of GeoExt 1.1?

Tags: javascript, geoext, deployment

The latest version of GeoExt that is available for download at http://geoext.org/downloads.html (version 1.1) appears to be a development version. They are individual files with whitespace and comments.

Usualy there is a [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29), compress version of javascript libraries available, to be used in production environment.

Nowhere  could I find such a version for GeoExt 1.1. Is there a deployment build available?

Comment: Good question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you unzip the file, there is a 135 kB minified GeoExt.js in the `GeoExt/script` folder.

The Development version is present at the  `GeoExt/lib/GeoExt.js` location,

while the compressed & minified version is located at `GeoExt/script/GeoExt.js`.